# data not worked properly in $.ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What the problem this script not working properly?

```
$(".clik_for_fetch").click(function(){
  var request="id="+$(this).attr("fetch_id");
  $.ajax({
            url:"pro/userlist.php",
            data:request,
            dataType:"html",
            type:'POST', 
            data:JSON.stringify(request),
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            success:function(result){
                  $(".table-striped tbody").html(result);
             },
            complete: function(){
            }
    });
});
```

and 
number of page

```
while($total_rows > 0)
                {

                    echo '<li><a href="#" class="clik_for_fetch" fetch_id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    $i++;
                    $total_rows--;

                }
```

The result of var_dump($_POST) is

```
array (size=1)
  '"id' => string '1"' (length=2)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're selecting a `<tbody>` tag. You cannot insert list elements `<li>` there.

Comment: You are specifying the `data` property twice. Try removing the second one.

Comment: Don't stringify data if you want it to be sent as post vars. If you instead want it sent as a JSON string in the request body, continue doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntactic

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clik_for_fetch").click(function(){
  var data ={
      id : $(this).attr("fetch_id")
  }
  $.ajax({
            url:"cp.php",
            data:data,
            dataType:"html",
            type:'POST', 

            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            success:function(result){
                  $(".table-striped tbody").html(result);
             },
            complete: function(){
            }
    });
});
});



</script>
```

Comment: This script its not working for me.but remove first line and end line its work properly.